# Why is SparkR-dropna not giving me the desired output?

Tags: r, na, sparkr

I have applied the following code on airquality dataset available in R, which has some missing values. I want to omit the rows which has NAs

```
library(SparkR)
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0" "sparkr-shell"')

sc <- sparkR.init("local",sparkHome = "/Users/devesh/Downloads/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6")

sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

path<-"/Users/devesh/work/airquality/"

aq <- read.df(sqlContext,path,source = "com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true")

head(dropna(aq,how="any"))
```

```
Ozone Solar_R Wind Temp Month Day
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
```

The NAs still exist in the output.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing values in native R are represented with a logical constant, `<NA>`. SparkR DataFrames represents missing values with NULL. If you use createDataFrame() to turn a local R data.frame into a distributed SparkR DataFrame, SparkR will automatically convert `<NA>` to NULL. However, if you are creating a SparkR DataFrame by reading in data from a file using read.df(), you may have strings of "NA", but not R logical constant `<NA>` missing value representations. String "NA" is not automatically converted to NULL, so dropna() will not consider it as a missing value.

If you have "NA" strings in your csv you might filter them rather than using dropna():

> filtered_aq <- filter(aq, aq$Ozone != "NA" & aq$Solar_R != "NA")
>
> head(filtered_aq)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. so how do we convert the entire "NA" in the sparkR data frame and convert it to NULL?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a different example for your reference for removing `NA`:

```
>data_local <- data.frame(Id=1:4, Age=c(40, 52, 25, NA))
>data <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, data_local)

>head(data)
 Id Age
1  1  40
2  2  52
3  3  25
4  4  NA

>head(dropna(data,how="any"))
Id Age
1  1  40
2  2  52
3  3  25
```

Comment: I think the problem is with reading of csv files. read.df is not considering NAs in the CSV file